# Why do i see the NaN for total price?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ahve already the script almost finished, but the total price is not showing up i still see `NaN` as results for the total price, why is this? and how can i quick fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/9zPTA/135/

This is my jquery code:

```
$("input").on("keyup", function () {
    var $input = $(this);
    var howMany = parseInt($input.val());
    var unitAmount = parseInt($input.parent().prev().text().replace("€", ""));
    var total = howMany ? howMany * unitAmount : 0;
    $input.parent().next().text("€ " + total);

    var total = 0;
    $("tbody tr td:last-child").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text().replace("€","") || 0);
    });
    $("#total").html("€ " + total);
});
```

Comment: Your selector was the problem. Please see my answer below with correctly working demo.

Comment: @Drakes Check my comment on your answer, Thanks again Drakes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector, and the brackets typo, are the problems. The brackets typo on `parseInt`

```
total += parseInt($(this).text().replace("€","") || 0);
```

parses `$(this).text().replace("€","") || 0` which is not what you want.

Also, you were erroneously including the final row's `<td>` (which holds the current total!) in your total calculation. This resulted in the increasing total you were experiencing.

Change

```
$("tbody tr td:last-child")
```

to

```
$(".tdPrice.tdDarker")
```

Try this:

```
var total = 0;
$(".tdPrice.tdDarker").each(function() {
    var val = parseInt($(this).text().replace("€",""));
    total += isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;
});
$("#total").html("€ " + total);
```

---

**Aside:** Sometimes you have entries with no money value, like

```
<td class="tdPrice"> <div id="u_KiloFineSilver"></div></td>
```

versus

```
<td class="tdPrice">€ 10 <div id="u_barFineSilver"></div></td>
```

which will cause an NaN in the subtotal, but with my solution above the final total will not be NaN.

---

> How can I hide the "0" value if someone enters, for example, 3 and then hits backspace?

Change

```
$input.parent().next().text("€ " + total);
```

to

```
$input.parent().next().text("€ " + (total > 0 ? total : ""));
```

---

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9ka2u5px/1/

Comment: Thanks men! I appreciate it, But how i can i hide the : "0" value if some enter for a example: 3 als value and hit backspace again? then you see : 0 how can i hide that?

Comment: This is an additional question... but it was a quick solve. Please see my answer above.

Comment: Thanks again! One last question, how can i also hide the 0 for the total price?

Comment: Thanks Bro! Respect for you! Have a nice day!

Comment: I'm not ;) forget that

Answer (score 0):

Change `total += parseInt($(this).text().replace("€","") || 0);` to `total += parseInt($(this).text().replace("€","") | 0);`